# How can I install iOS4 and 5 SDKs on the same machine?

Tags: ios

I would like to be able to target iOS4 and iOS5 on the same Mac. Specifically, I have a need to test web apps in both versions of the simulator. I am a registered iOS developer but can't see where to download the earlier SDK in the iOS dev centre. Host OS is Snow Leopard 10.6.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in XCode Preferences -> Downloads -> Components. The older version of the simulator will be downloaded and installed, then available in the Simulator Menu Under Hardware -> Version

Answer (score 5):

You can install iOS 5 and set the development target for whichever version you wish to test. Simulators for 4 & 5 will be included.

See Deployment Target in the Project & Targets.

Comment: I am not using XCode in this case and just want to test a web app in both iOS4 and 5. The simulator only has version 5 available in Hardware -> Version.